# JSSOR slider: Remove inline style from html

Tags: html, css, jssor

I am trying to remove the inline style from the thumbnail navigator skin but am not sure how to treat this bit of html.

```
    <!-- What is "div u=" please?
    Is "u" a class here?
    How does that translate to a CSS selektor? -->
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">


<!-- Here I can simply write ".p" as a CSS selektor?
    How does the CSS selektor then know it 
    has to do with "u=prototype"? -->
    <div u="prototype" class="p" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 72px; HEIGHT: 72px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">


        <!-- Here I can simply write ".i" as a CSS selektor?
        How does the CSS selektor then know it 
        has to do with "u=thumbnailtemplate"? -->
        <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="i" style="position:absolute;"></div>
        <div class="o">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I have never come across `div u=` in general or `div u=slides, prototype, thumbnailtemplate, etc`.

For better understanding, can one simply assign letters to divs and then assign those letters functions with jQuery? Where in your code is `slides, prototype, thumbnailtemplate` referenced? I would like to learn about this technique please. **Can you provide a link or reference to this please**?

Thank you for any help.

By the way, I have looked at a ton of sliders and finally choose this one. I am just about to start development with it and Bootstrap 3.3.2, I hope it will all work out.

Very **NICE** work from what I can see on the demos. They **ALL** work on my smartphone out of the pocket, something most of the other sliders did not manage. Well done!

If you don't mind me saying this, the only thing I would change is provide a folder "CSS" with only the CSS rules for the arrow-, bullet- and thumbnail- navigators, including the inline styles of the `span`, `div=u` and generally all elements that have inline styles.

Apart from that solid work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "div u=" please?

Re: There are so many elements in the slider, the 'u' attribute is customize attribute, jssor js library read 'u' attribute to identify the usage of an element.

Is "u" a class here?
How does that translate to a CSS selektor?

Re: 'u' is not a class. You can try $("div[u=slides]") to select the element in javascript. And you can add your own class as follows,

```
<div u="slides" class="yourclassname">
```

Here I can simply write ".p" as a CSS selektor?

Re: yes, you can. please use the following format to prevent conflicts from other sliders in the same page,

```
.jssort07 .p {
    /* css */
}
.jssort07 .pav {
    /* css when active */
}
.jssort07 .pdn {
    /* css when mouse down */
}
.jssort07 .p:hover {
    /* css when mouse over */
}
```

How does the CSS selektor then know it has to do with "u=prototype"?

Re: No need to think about it. The 'u=prototype' lets jssor js know it is the prototype element of thumbnails.

Here I can simply write ".i" as a CSS selektor?

Re: Yes you can. But please use the following format to avoid conflicts.

```
.jssort07 .p .i {
    /* css */
}
.jssort07 .pav .i {
    /* css when active */
}
.jssort07 .pdn .i {
    /* css when mouse down */
}
.jssort07 .p:hover .i {
    /* css when mouse over */
}
```

How does the CSS selektor then know it has to do with "u=thumbnailtemplate"?

Re: Please ignore it.